# Can't unbind click from nested <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function that allows me to expand and collapse an unordered list by clicking on the list item, but the problem is in the lowest level LI I have a table with a checkbox embedded, and when the user clicks on the table [edit] the background image of the parent li is shown.

The way I see it there are two main routes to solve this, somehow just remove the background image for just the child li or to unbind the click event for the child li.  I am trying to unbind the click handler on the lowest level LI, but it just won't work. Below is a simplified version.  A user shouldn't be able to click on the td cells.

If you view the jsfiddle I can't add the png files that will completely replicate the problem to where you can see the issue, but as long as the 'alert' triggers on the child li you can tell the child li is still clickable.

http://jsfiddle.net/3CgQ6/9/

#### HTML

```
<ul id="expList">
  <li>Category 1
     <ul>
        <li class="detailLI"> Category 1.1
           <table>
             <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Part A</td></tr>
             <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Part B</td></tr>
             <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Part C</td></tr>
           </table>
        </li>
        <li class="detailLI"> Category 1.2
           <table>
             <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Part D</td></tr>
             <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Part E</td></tr>
           </table>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### JavaScript

```
    $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')    
        .click( function(event) {
            //If line item is expandable but has no line items then call the service to retrieve data
            if($(event.target).hasClass('collapsed') && $(event.target).find('li').length==0){                  
                retrieveResults($(event.target));
            }
            //Toggle the lists if they show or not
            $(event.target).toggleClass('expanded');
            $(event.target).children('ul').slideToggle('medium');
            event.stopPropagation();
            $('.detailLI').unbind("click");
        })
        .addClass('collapsed')
            .removeClass('expanded')
            .children('ul').hide();
```

Comment: posting a jsfiddle would be helpful here.

Comment: Especially because I'm unclear about the problem you're having. Posting just this code in a fiddle gives reasonable behavior (http://jsfiddle.net/ccross59/3CgQ6/)

Comment: Hi Colleen, unfortunately I am unable to add all the details of the list in jsfiddle, since there are some rather complex ajax calls that dynamically populate the ul and li's.  I was hoping that my problem wasn't related to that, but after playing around with the jsfiddle it looks more and more like that is the problem.  I'll see if I can narrow the problem down and update the scenario.

Comment: After additional research I've identified the issue is from a background image that is used for the expand and collapse classes.  I don't have a way to add the gif files to the jsfiddle, but here is the link.  http://jsfiddle.net/3CgQ6/7/   If you were to use this example and add the png's manually the problem could be replicated.  I will update the question above.

Comment: So I marked Lokase as the correct answer as technically that is correct, however I was able to solve this a different route.  In the css (seen in js fiddle) the background image was being added to the 'expList .expand'.  To solve this problem I just had to add .filter('li') to the toggle class line.  What was happening was the expanded class was being added to the event.target.  So when I clicked on the table cell it was adding the background image.  By using filter I simply said only apply that background image to the event.target's that are LI's.    Thank you Colleen for getting me started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use on() and off() to bind/unbind events.  All other methods of binding/unbinding have been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a click event to the checkbox element and put your "event.stopPropagation" there to stop bubbling?